# Changing array value when condition is met in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Let's say I have an array `var arr = [3,4,5,6,7,9];` and I log the contents like this:

```
$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

As I log the contents I want to check if the current value is bigger than for example `var limit = 5;`.

If the current value is bigger than `limit` I want to replace/change that value to let's say the letter `A` and print it out as such. So my logged `arr` array would look like this `3,4,5,A,A,A`.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$.each(arr, function(k,v) {
  if (v > limit) {
    // set this specific value equal to limit
    // log changed value
  }
  console.log(v); // otherwise just log the value found
});
```

I tried this, but it does nothing, no errors either.

Comment: Your code seems alright. Except for a missing closing brace. While the first code snippet is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Also note that according to your comment, you are going to print each modified value _twice_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nsgch/8/

```
var arr = [3,4,5,6,7,9];
var limit = 5;

$.each(arr, function(k,v) {
  if (v > limit) {
       arr[k] = 'A'; 
  }
  console.log( arr[k] ); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply write somethig like this to handle these scenarios...

Imagine you have:

```
const arr = [0, 1, 6, 12, 0, 78];
```

Use something like:

```
arr.map(a => a === 0 ? "a" :a);
```

and the result will be:

```
["a", 1, 6, 12, "a", 78];
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you were doing the "set this specific value equal to limit". If you were doing;

```
$.each(arr, function(k,v) {
  if (v > limit) {
    v = "A";
    // log changed value
  }
  console.log(v); // otherwise just log the value found
});
```

You were changing only the local variable `v`, rather than the element `arr[k]`. You can either update `arr[k]` like in [@san.chez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16881899/444991), or use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/);

```
var filtered = $.map(arr, function(v,k) {
  if (v > limit) {
    return "A";
  }

  return v;
});
```

... then `filtered` would be your array `[1,2,4,A,A]`, and `arr` would be unchanged. Note the swapping of `k` and `v` parameters; jQuery is consistent like that <sup>/sarcasm</sup>

---

Note also that both of your code samples are missing the closing `}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [3,4,5,6,7,9];
arr=arr.map(function(elem){ return elem>5?"A":elem; });
arr.forEach(function(elem){
    console.log(elem);
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It's worth noting that `Array.prototype.map` is an ES5 method, and ***not*** cross-browser; the [ES5 shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) can be added to ensure support for older browsers

Comment: As far as I can see, there is a compatibility info in the link I posted. And in case you have an older browser, you can download a new one for free :)

Comment: I know there's a compatibility section in the link you posted (the shim *I* linked to links to that section!), but just for the *drive-byers* who don't click your link, it's important to note.